# Updating a TextView once per second while the App is Running

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming, but I'm quite familiar with Java and so...

In this app, I need to create something like a Death/Birth counter and a Total Population Counter, so I need the String at the Activity to be updated each second, but I can't seen to find any solution.

This is my Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static int nasc;
    static int mortes;
    static int popTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        nasc = 0;
        mortes = 0;
        popTotal = 0;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView view = new TextView(this);
        Boolean menu = false;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        while (menu == false) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    view.setText("Births : " + getNasc() + ".");
                    view.append("\n");
                    view.append("Deaths : " + getMortes() + ".");
                    view.append("\n");
                    view.append("Total Population : " + getPopTotal() + ".");
                    setContentView(view);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    private int getPopTotal() {
        popTotal = nasc - mortes;
        return popTotal;
    }

    private int getMortes() {
        mortes = (int) (mortes + 1.7);
        return mortes;
    }

    private int getNasc() {
        nasc = nasc + 3;
        return nasc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.textView) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: add a TextView in your activity_main and update in instead of setContentView everytime. second point: use a local String and update that String with your data then setText by that string ways better for me. let's try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is remove the while loop, and just re-run the Runnable if `menu == false` each second after updating the UI with the new totals.

I just got this implementation working by making the Runnable a member variable instead of it being an anonymous class, using a StringBuilder to build up the text for the TextView, and re-running the Runnable if `menu` is still false at the completion of each run.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static int nasc;
    static int mortes;
    static int popTotal;
    TextView view;
    Handler handler;
    Boolean menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nasc = 0;
        mortes = 0;
        popTotal = 0;
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        menu = false;
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(updateText, 1000);
    }

    public Runnable updateText = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Births : " + getNasc() + ".");
            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append("Deaths : " + getMortes() + ".");
            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append("Total Population : " + getPopTotal() + ".");

            view.setText(sb.toString());

            if (menu == false){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    //.................
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, my major mistake was in the using of the While Loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nasc = 0;
    mortes = 0;
    popTotal = 0;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_id);

String allText="";
Boolean menu = false;
Handler handler = new Handler();
while (menu == false) {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            allText+="Births : " + getNasc() + ".";
            allText+="\n";
            allText+="Deaths : " + getMortes() + ".";
            allText+="\n";
            allTExt+="Total Population : " + getPopTotal() + ".";
            view.setText(allText);
            allText="";//reset the string
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

}`

In your activity_main.xml inside yout TextView declaration add

```
<TextView ...
   ... <!--other params that you have set-->
   android:id="@+id/textview_id"
   ... />
```

Comment: Hmm, I think having the while loop in `onCreate()` would prevent the Activity lifecycle callbacks from executing properly, as it would never get into `onResume()` until `menu` equals true.

Comment: thanks  we can you ScheduledExecutorServic answer given below and update textview inside that

Answer (score 0):

**try this way me this help u**

```
public class test extends Activity {

private TextView textView;
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
set();
}


private void set(){

final String text ="A n d r o i d P r o g r a m m i n g";
final String[] words = text.toString().split(" ");
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(""+words[i]);
        i++;
        if(i < words.length) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
});
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

import this :
    //
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
    //
and use this for every one minute :

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecut = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This run every one minute
    scheduleTaskExecut.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
//in this Methos Update Your Text as You Need
UpdateYourText();

      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```